# Swift ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral - How exactly does it work?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Taken from iOs 10 Programming Fundamentals:

"Because Nest adopts ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, we can pass an Int where a nest is expected, and our init(integerLiteral:) will be called AUTOMATICALLY....."

```
struct Nest : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
     var eggCount : Int = 0
     init() {}
     init(integerLiteral val: Int) {
          self.eggCount = val
     }
}
```

Okay so my question is this...How does it get called automatically though?? My logic runs into a brick wall when I try to figure out why. From what I see, you can say:

```
var eggie : Nest = 5
```

but... okay where is the logic in how the number 5 after the equal sign is actually a shorthand for:

```
var eggie : Nest = Nest(5)
```

AKA the 'standard' way of initializing a new instance...

Is that just something hidden deep inside the ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral protocol that is handling that transformation?

Thanks

Comment: The *compiler* transforms `var eggie : Nest = 5` to `var eggie = Nest(integerLiteral: 5)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *compiler magic*, so unfortunately you cannot declare such a protocol yourself. :(

It has nothing to do with the internal workings of the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. The compiler only sees a variable of type `Nest` on the left and an integer literal on the right. It thinks,

> Oh! The `Nest` type conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`! And I see an integer literal. This means that I can change the integer literal to `Nest(integerLiteral: 5)`!

It's as simple as that. This is also true for other `ExpressibleByXXXLiteral` protocols.

You cannot declare your own `ExpressibleByMyClass` protocol because the compiler doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

The `ExpressibleBy*Literal` protocols are Swift protocols to "hook" into special compiler behaviour. Without the compiler doing the lifting in the back, they wouldn't be able to do anything.